# How do I create a hover box over image, if the image has a transition effect?

Tags: css

I've been trying to get a hover box with text to appear over an image once the user hovers over it. The problem is, I have a transition effect on my image, of which when the user hovers over, it becomes larger. I need to simulate the same thing with the hover box, but I am having difficulties with the positioning and transition.

Below is my code:

```css
.img__wrap {
  position: relative;
  height: 200px;
}

.img__description {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  color: #fff;
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: hidden;
  transition: opacity .2s, visibility .2s;
}

.img__wrap:hover .img__description {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 0.5;
  transition-delay: 0.2s;
  background: grey;
  -moz-transform: scale(1.8);
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.8);
  transform: scale(1.8);
  width: 200px;
  position: absolute;
}

.picture {
  width: 200px;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}

.picture:hover {
  -moz-transform: scale(1.8);
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.8);
  transform: scale(1.8);
}
```

```html
<div class="img__wrap">
  <a href="myHomePage.html">
    <img src="http://cdn3-www.dogtime.com/assets/uploads/gallery/30-impossibly-cute-puppies/impossibly-cute-puppy-21.jpg" alt="hover box is supposed to encapsulate picture" class="picture">

    <p class="img_description">
      This is the paragraph inside of the hover box describing the picture.
    </p>

  </a>
  <h1>My Image Sample Above</h1>


</div>
```

No matter how I try to position the hover box, it never fully encapsulates the picture. If I put it to position absolute, then the position is off on all other devices other than that screen size.

Is there a way to have a hover box over a transitioning picture?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a little tweaking of your code, I managed to achieve what you're looking for.

The thing to note is that you have to encapsulate your image hover effect in the wrapper hover event.

Check the snippet below:

```css
.img__wrap {
  position: relative;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.sample {
  width: 200px;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}

.img__description {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  color: #fff;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.2s;
}


/* There is where the magic happens */

.img__wrap:hover .img__description {
  opacity: 1;
}

.img__wrap:hover .sample {
  -moz-transform: scale(1.8);
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.8);
  transform: scale(1.8);
}
```

```html
<div class="img__wrap">
  <a href="myHomePage.html">
    <img src="https://placehold.it/200x200" alt="hover box is supposed to encapsulate picture" class="sample ">
    <p class="img__description">
      This is where the hover box should pop up explaining the picture.
    </p>
  </a>
  <h1 class="iconFont ">My Image Sample Above</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: This worked. Now I realize I don't have to put the transform effect into the description itself. Was there a reason for the overflow:hidden that you put in the img wrap?

Comment: Pure aesthetic. Otherwise, the picture was growing partly off the viewport.